# How I/O request works in Linux Kernel

Tags: io, linux-kernel

Good day! May I have a question about how I/O works on low-level? More specifically, my question is how many bytes can be handled in the one I/O requests?
For example, if we read an input document line by line (let's say a document containing 10 lines), the Linux kernel will submit all 10 lines using one I/O request or it will submit 10 I/O request separately? Thank you in advance for any comments or suggestions.

Comment: How would a disk know what a line is?

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this question. Let me give an overview of the layers of IO as per Linux kernel.

```
1. You perform a line read from application
```

**Userspace**

```
2. Read/write system call moves the control to kernel
```

**Kernel**

```
3. VFS layer comes into picture and find the filesystem the file belongs to 
4. Filesystem specific read is invoked, say ext3_read 
5. Filesystem sees if the data in Page cache, if yes then returns the data 
6. If data is not in pagecache the using the file Inode, filesystem gets the sector number of the disk, this File block number is mapped to 
7. Filesystem prepares an IOVEC, a structure for performing IO from disk. It consists of vector of RAM pages and sector number fetched from the Inode map.
8. The IOVEC is converted to SCSI/NVMe command and send to Lowerlayer device driver to read from the disk.
```

If you perform multiple lines read then you do multiple system call to kernel. The filesystem in kernel may fetch the data from page cache, or issues read to the disk.